# Using Join to combine lists inside of lists?

Tags: python

I would like to use the join method to join strings inside of a list, I am not sure if it is possible or not but I was hoping you guys could help me out!

I have this list (a list within a list within a list):

```
[ [ ['a', 'd', 't', 'a', 'j'], ['u', 's', 'h', 'w'], ['p', 'b', 'q', 'l', 't', 'a'] ], [ ['y', 'a'], ['t', 's'] ] ]
```

And what I am trying to output from the function is something like this:

```
[ ['adtajushwpbwlta'], ['yats'] ]
```

The code that I have tried is using a nested for loop, but the problem I get with this is that it just turns everything into one big string

```
adtajushwpbwltayats
```

I am just a beginner, I would really appreciate it if you guys could use really basic code and methods (no 're' and stuff like that). Also if join is not the appropriate method to use, please let me know which method would be better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you want you can use a combination of `join` and list comprehensions:

```
>>> letters = [[['a', 'd', 't', 'a', 'j'], ['u', 's', 'h', 'w'], ['p', 'b', 'q', 'l', 't', 'a']], [ ['y', 'a'], ['t', 's']]]
>>> [["".join(["".join(a) for a in b])] for b in letters]
[['adtajushwpbqlta'], ['yats']]
```

Note that this will only work for the same number of nested lists in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
record = [ [ ['a', 'd', 't', 'a', 'j'], ['u', 's', 'h', 'w'], ['p', 'b', 'q', 'l', 't', 'a'] ], [ ['y', 'a'], ['t', 's'] ] ]
import itertools
result = [ ["".join(list(itertools.chain(*r)))] for r in record ]
print result

output : [['adtajushwpbqlta'], ['yats']]
```

With the use of **itertools** you can achive this in single iteration.